# libgdx on android: egl ERROR 12292

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, egl

I have created a simple game with libgdx in eclipse.
The game runs fine when starting it in desktop mode. But when actually running it on my device I get the above mentioned error. The screen stays black and the game does not work.

Comment: Can you include the catlog output?  Also, which version of the Android Tools are you using?